# Import another file (and it's functions) into discord.py main file

Tags: python, discord.py, python-import

I'd like to import functions from another file into my main discord.py file and run them, however my bot doesn't log in when I import the file. Both the discord bot file and the other file work fine by themselves.

I have the following discord bot code in Python:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import TwitterSentiments

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$",help_command=None)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")

@client.command(name="stock")
async def _stock(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Enter ticker symbol: ")
    # conditions are met:
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    avg_list = TwitterSentiments.find_tweets(msg.content)
    myEmbed = discord.Embed(title="Output", description=f"Your ticker symbol was {msg.content} and the average score is {avg_list}!")
    await ctx.send(embed=myEmbed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run("SECRET")
```

And I have another file in the same folder named TwitterSentiments.py:

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

#Consumer keys
consumer_key = 'SECRET'
consumer_secret = 'SECRET'

#Access tokens
access_token = 'SECRET'
access_token_secret = 'SECRET'

#Authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Main function to get tweets
def find_tweets(ticker_symbol):
    #Search for tweets with ticker symbol
    public_tweets = api.search(ticker_symbol)
    #Empy list for average of all sentiments
    sentiment_average_list = []

    for tweet in public_tweets:
        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        sentiment_average_list.append(analysis.sentiment.polarity)

    return sentiment_average_list
```

How do I import `TwitterSentiments.py` and it's functions? When I try `import TwitterSentiments` or `from TwitterSentiments import find_tweets` my discord bot doesn't log into the server, but otherwise it works.

Comment: No errors? It means function is called. Put a "print("Hello")" in your find_tweets and you'll see that it runs.

Comment: @RustamA. When I run the discord.py file without importing ```TwitterSentiments```, a message pops up in the console "We have logged in as Bot#2192" and the bot goes online in my discord server. However, when I do import the other file, this does not happen

Comment: This probably mean that your logging never gets executed. You are calling usual function from async one. Put a lot of prints: print(1), print(2),... in different lines and see: what number is printed last - that is where function stopped. After this you'll know in what line your problem is.

Comment: I guess by importing TwitterSentiments, it blocks the discord bot since its not async. You should either find a async way to use `tweepy` or use `TwitterSentiments` as a subprocess, rather than import it

Comment: I would agree with @Guddi please read more on [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)